# SSRS PDF Not complete render when it's scheduled or render online

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, pdf-generation, rendering, ssrs-2012

I have this problem, on ssrs i have a report with a specific structure of 82 pages grouped by Area. If i open the report on Reportserver or reder it in Excel i see the correct structure and all the report:

[image]

But if i schedule in PDF or i render from internet the report in PDF this it the result:
[image]

As you can see i haven't north america, row o china. It's like reporting stop the rendering of the report and do nothing. (in the pdf he prints 3 blank page after europa page)

Comment: Try placing a TextBox in the report footer with the expression: `=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF",Globals!TotalPages,"")`.  If this is a problem with a timeout, using the TotalPages global variable will force everything to be processed before it starts rendering the first page.  This causes indomitable delays when trying to view a lengthy report, but it might be a solution here.

Comment: Thx it's works. you saved my life.

Comment: No problem - glad to hear it helped.  I've retyped it as an actual answer with a little more detail below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issues like this can be caused by an internal timeout.  Normally SSRS tries to start rendering right away, which is why the first page comes up quickly and navigating to subsequent pages has a delay.  That's usually the desired behavior.

However, you can force it to all of that processing up front by including an element such as the TotalPages global variable.  That way, all of the pages have to be generated before the first page is rendered.  When viewing a lengthy report this can cause very noticeable delays, so even here you would only want to do this during the export.

- Just create a TextBox in the report footer with the following expression:

`=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF",Globals!TotalPages,"")`

Or use the more presentable:

`="Page " & Globals!PageNumber & IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="PDF"," of " & Globals!TotalPages,"")`

If you end up having problems with other export formats, you can switch that to test for RenderFormat.IsInteractive instead.